# ASP.NET MVC Dictionary<string,string> output in view

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, viewbag

Controller / C#:

```
public Action GetData()
{
    ViewBag.InputData = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
         ["Name"] = "Simon Lin",
         ["Age"] = "18"
    };
    return View();
}
```

View / HTML:

```
@foreach (var keyValuePair in (ViewBag.InputData as Dictionary<string, string>))
{
     <input type="text" name=@keyValuePair.Key value="" placeholder=@keyValuePair.Value />
}
```

But in the result, first input's placeholder only show "Simon", Final HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="Name" value="" placeholder="Simon" Lin="">
```

Comment: You need to quote it - `placeholder="@keyValuePair.Value"` (ditto for the `name` attribute)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing quotes around the variables in your view:

```
<input type="text" name="@keyValuePair.Key" value="" placeholder="@keyValuePair.Value" />
                        ^                 ^                      ^                   ^
```

Comment: Oh... Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0):

Enclosed Name and Placeholder in quotes

```
@foreach (var keyValuePair in (ViewBag.InputData as Dictionary<string, string>))
{
   <input type="text" name="@keyValuePair.Key" value="" 
 placeholder="@keyValuePair.Value"/>
}
```